# Expressing one gradient in terms of the other

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose I have the following relation:
$\mathbf{v}=t|\mathbf{k}|^{t-2}\mathbf{k}$ where $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ are $d-$dimensional vectors and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to express $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}$ in terms of $\nabla_{\mathbf{k}}$. Is it possible? What is the expression?

I think it should just be $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}} = \frac{1}{t|\mathbf{k}|^{t-2}}\nabla_{\mathbf{k}}$ but that is possibly not correct.

Comment: By the way, you should add what you've tried to the content to make it clear that :1.you aren't doing a homework question, 2. you've tried it at least once and is still stuck in some place there.

Comment: Plus, I am a 15 year old and have no idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: I have added that

Comment: Good then - but I don't get to see it. Is it occurring towards the end or present in the beginning ?

Comment: At the end, I have added what I think is correct